# Can you use GTK3 StWidgets in glade looking in the menu it does not seem to be a widget

Tags: widget, gtk3, gnome, glade

I have looked through the available widgets in glade 3.20 and can not find anything called StWidget.

Inspecting Gnome Maps, Builder and Nautilus the button is listed as an StWidget, the closest I can find in glade is a MenuButton Widget.

[image: Builder Example Python is the StWidget]

I basically want to make a funky dropdown widget like a lot of the modern gnome apps have started using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty much the farthest thing from an authoritative answer, so I really hope I'm corrected by a developer at some point in the future. However I was researching this class of widgets, so at least I've discovered a few things.

The St widgets are used within gnome-shell, and are not actually related to GTK in implementation.  They are implemented on Clutter, so they are from a different linage.  I was not able to confirm their future place within GTK, however they've been mentioned in the initial GTK4 discussions.

It also looks like no real documentation exists, so using the St's would be playing on the development edge.  Not sure how you found the St widgets in nautilus though, I thought applications were still all GTK... excluding any gnome-shell integration components, those could have St widgets.

If your making Applications, stick with the mainline GTK.  However if you wanted a menu like that for gnome-shell, have you investigated making a gnome-shell extension?

Comment: your quite right, i was using the inspector i was looking at the wrong thing in the end, any how I managed to reproduce what i was after. like you say there is not mush info on these stwidgets and how they fit into the picture.